# Linker Input | Add lib to multiple projects

Tags: c++, linker, multiple-projects

I need t add a .lib input to multiple projects in Visual Studio 2008 (C++).

Is there a way to do it fast? I'm going project after project and clicking properties then going to the linker and adding the .lib manually..

Thank you,

Matias.

Answer (score 0):

If the `.lib` is produced by one of your own projects, you can add a project dependency to all the project that need your `.lib`.
This can be done by selecting each project in the Solution Explorer, right click, and go to Project Dependencies.

Microsoft has an [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that describes this in more detail.

Comment: Right, problem is that I have 91 projects that build and I need to go one by one, I was thinking maybe there was a faster way to add the dependency?

Comment: 91 is a lot... How about opening all project files (*.vcproj if i remember correctly) in your favorite text-editor, figure out a common entry in the spot where the `.lib` should be added, and search/replace those in there? It could help to copy one of your project files first, then add the library via Visual Studio in your original, and compare those two.